# Itemtpl usage sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to check a year value from drop down and depending on that I am setting my itemtpl. However I would like to know if this is possible . dropdownyearvalue is my drop down value which I am inserting in store and Year is a value inserted before in the same store.

```
       {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'Oct',
            // style: 'border-color: blue; border-style: solid;'
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for="month"><tpl if="status == 1 && month==1 && Year=='{dropdownyearvalue}'"><div class="planned"></div><tpl elseif="status == 2 && month==1"><div class="target"></div><tpl else><div id="nothing"></div></tpl></tpl>')

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you can push any data to your template using data property, just like in example.

```
config:{
    baseCls: 'hexagonList',
    records: null,

    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for="items"><div class="item" ref="{data.urlId}"><div class="hex"></div><div class="text">{data.label}</div></div></tpl>')
},

updateRecords: function(newRecords){

    this.setData({
        items: newRecords.items
    });
}
```